# What is the purpose of the extra wheel on the XB-70 main gear?

Tags: military, landing-gear, experimental-aircraft, xb-70-valkyrie

This photo of the [XB-70 Valkyrie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_XB-70_Valkyrie)'s main gear shows a small wheel between the two main wheels:

[image: XB-70 MLG]
<sup>Courtsey of [AirPigz.com](http://airpigz.com/blog/2012/1/29/day-2-airpigz-air-force-museum-meetup-1-28-12.html)</sup>

This smaller wheel doesn't touch the ground, though I can see where it might as the side walls of the main tires compress under landing weight.

The AirPigz site promised an explanation, but none has been forthcoming (in the 4+ years since that was posted), and I couldn't find any information on it on Wikipedia, either. Does anyone have any information (real or speculative) on what it's for?

Comment: Ha! I spotted that on the video that was posted the other day, but was too lazy to ask. Thanks!

Answer (score 75, accepted):

It is a sensing wheel that is part of the antiskid braking system. It contains an electronic sensor to measure the true groundspeed of the airplane. See [NASA Technical Note D-4836, *Landing Loads and Accelerations of the XB-70-1 Airplane* (1968)](http://www.nasa.gov/centers/dryden/pdf/87742main_H-471.pdf), bottom of page 3 of the document (page 5 on the PDF):

[image]

Comment: Wow! A quick and authoritative answer! Did you know this or is your Google-fu that good?

Comment: Call it a [lucky Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=xb-70+landing+gear+fifth+wheel).

Comment: Nice "lucky Google", then Fred! I'm sure I could have done the same, but it's good to have information gathered here on what's quickly become my favorite web-site. Thanks for the image embed, @mikeSowsun